# Initialize Non-Optional Property Before super.init call without duplicating code

Tags: swift, properties, initialization

One of the most frustrating situations for me in Swift is when I have a class like this:

```
class A: NSObject {
    var a: Int

    override init() {
        clear()
        super.init()
    }

    func clear() {
        a = 5
    }
}
```

Of course, this causes multiple compiler errors (`'self' used in method call 'clear' before 'super.init' call` and `Property 'self.a' not initialized at super.init call`.

And changing the order of the constructor lines only fixes the first error:

```
override init() {
    super.init()
    clear()
}
```

Usually, I end up doing one of two things. The first option is to make `a` an implicitly unwrapped optional, but I feel that this is terrible style because `a` will never be `nil` after the constructor returns:

```
var a: Int! = nil
```

The second option is to copy the functionality of my `clear()` function in the constructor:

```
override init() {
    a = 5
    super.init()
}
```

This works fine for this simplified example, but it unnecessarily duplicates a lot of code in more complex code bases.

Is there a way to initialize `a` without duplicating my `clear` function or making `a` an optional? If not, why not?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "why not" in this *specific* case is very straightforward. What you've written would allow me to write this:

```
class B: A {
    override func clear() {}
}
```

And then `a` would not be initialized. So what you've written can never be legal Swift.

That said, there's a deeper version that probably could be legal but isn't. If you marked the class `final` or if this were a struct, then the compiler might be able to prove that everything is correctly initialized along all code paths by inlining all the possible method calls, but the compiler doesn't do all that today; it's too complicated. The compiler just says "my proof engine isn't that strong so knock it off."

IMO, the correct solution here is a `!` type, though I wouldn't add `= nil`. That's misleading. I would write it this way:

```
class A: NSObject {
    var a: Int!    // You don't have to assign `!` types; they're automatically nil

    override init() {
        super.init()
        clear()
    }

    func clear() {
        a = 5
    }
}
```

This says "I am taking responsibility to make sure that `a` is going to be set before it is used." Which is exactly what you are doing. I do this all the time when I need to pass self as a delegate. I wish the compiler could explore every possible code path across every method call, but it doesn't today (and given what it might do to compile times, maybe I don't wish that).

> but I feel that this is terrible style because a will never be nil after the constructor returns

That's exactly the point of `!` types. They should *never* be nil by the time any other object can get their hands on it. If it could be `nil`, then you shouldn't be using `!`. I agree that `!` is *dangerous* (since the compiler is no longer helping you), but it's not bad style.

The only other reasonable approach IMO is to assign default values. I wouldn't use the actual values of course; that would an invitation to subtle bugs. I would just use some default value to get things in place.

```
class A: NSObject {
    var a = Int.min // -1 might be reasonable. I just like it to be clearly wrong
    override init() {
        super.init()
        clear()
    }

    func clear() {
        a = 5
    }
}
```

I don't love this approach, though I've used it in a few places. I don't think it gives you any safety over the `!` (it won't crash, but you'll almost certainly give you subtle behavioral bugs, and I'd rather the crash). This is a place where the programmer must pay attention because the compiler is powerful enough to prove everything's correct, and the point of `!` is to mark those places.

Comment: The "why not" makes perfect sense, I've not yet had to subclass one of my own classes in Swift so I never thought about that situation. I wish there was a more elegant solution, but your answer makes it clear why there isn't. Coming from a Java background, I guess assigning default values (or ! with nil) isn't really different from what happens in Java, it's just that Java does it automatically and there's no way around it so it feels more natural. Thanks!